# RxJava BehaviorSubject and Consumer - is there a memory leak here?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

first time using RxJava, remembered that I read a lot about memory leaks in RxJava, so afraid I might be creating a memory leak here - am I? And if I am, how do I fix it? Should I create a `Consumer` member object and do something with it upon `onStop` or `onDestroy`? (The lambdra in `.subscribe` is for a `Consumer` with an `accept` method

```
void onCreate() {
    keyboardChangeSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();
    keyboardChangeSubject
            .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(isKeyBoardOpen -> {
                myButton.setVisibility(isKeyBoardOpen ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            });
}

@Override
protected void onKeyboardChange(boolean isKeyboardOpen) {
    keyboardChangeSubject.onNext(isKeyboardOpen);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should have it disposed when the Activity gets destroyed by adding the returned `Disposable` to a `CompositeDisposable`, which comes in handy when you have more than one flow to be tracked:

```
final CompositeDisposble cd = new CompositeDisposable();

void onCreate() {
    keyboardChangeSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();
    cd.add(
        keyboardChangeSubject
        .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(isKeyBoardOpen -> {
            myButton.setVisibility(isKeyBoardOpen ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        })
    );
}

@Override
protected void onKeyboardChange(boolean isKeyboardOpen) {
    keyboardChangeSubject.onNext(isKeyboardOpen);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
     cd.clear();
}
```